# Where is x from?

Tags: scala, function

```
object Test1 {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        foo(10)
    }

    def foo(a: Int) = {

        println(x = 20)
    }
}
```

I can use x, so where is x from ?
I am very confused
[image]

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/named-arguments.html

Comment: look at signature `println` method, it takes `x` argument and you are passing x using named arguments https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Console$.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with `locally`, so now naming its parameter is deprecated. Probably `println` deserves the same treatment.

Now, in arg parens, `x = 1` never means assignment; you have to use block syntax for that.

```
scala> { var x = 0 ; locally(x = 1) ; x }
                               ^
       warning: naming parameter x is deprecated.
res0: Int = 0

scala> { var x = 0 ; println(x = 1) ; x }
1
res1: Int = 0

scala> { var x = 0 ; println { x = 1 } ; x }
()
res2: Int = 1

scala> { var y = 0 ; println(y = 1) ; y }
                               ^
       error: unknown parameter name: y
       Note that assignments in argument position are no longer allowed since Scala 2.13.
       To express the assignment expression, wrap it in brackets, e.g., `{ y = ... }`.
```

Answer (score 0):

x = 20 , this is NAMED ARGUMENTS